# can one iis worker process have many application domain?

Tags: asp.net, iis

can one iis worker process have many application domain? if does then what if one of the application fails, will it affect the other application running using same worker process?

in other words i have read in many articles that if one of the application sharing same app pool fails then it does affect other application in that pool

however, i also read that one process can have many appDomain (one for each application) and if one application fails it does not effect other application in that process

a bit confused

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if an apppool shared by multiple websites is stopped intentionally or due to some other failure (and it doesn't restart automatically) all the websites sharing that apppool will be stop working.

Yes an apppool can service many domains, either as separate sites, or multi-tennanted in the same site.

Comment: so you are saying if application fail in particular appDomain then that application pool will not be affected. but if worker process fails  due to some reason then it will affect all the application using it.

Comment: If you go to your apppool in IIS and look at advanced settings you will see all the failure settings.  Apppools automatically restart on failures (by default 5 times?), and on a regular basis (1740mins) to protect your site from memory leaks and problems.  App pools are always restarting...  However if there is a serious problem they will go down and wont come back causing the problem you describe in your question, and in that case all websites that are being serviced by that apppool will stop working.